# Adding page?=$page

Tags: variables, get

I'm trying to do something where users that register to my site, instead of having alot of PHP files changing in the URL loading a Variable.

Cut to the chase,
I'm trying to make it so when they goto the link "Test Page"
It loads http://example.com/page?=testpage instead of testpage.php

When they goto page?=testpage it loads testpage.php whether than having a load of PHP files that can be seen in the URL.

Thanks,
Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this in your `index.php` file.

```
<?php
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    include_once($page);
?>
```

Then you can use a `.htaccess` file and [mod_rewrite](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708) to redirect from `page.php` to http://dummycode.com/?page=page.php

Comment: I just did it simply,
<?php
if( $_GET['page'] == "testpage")
{
 echo "Kick";
}
?>